# plotly-- Making multiple lines with checklist

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm new in plotly. I'm making checklist with 2 lines vertically without making another checklist on the side. Is there any way to make another line?

```
                dcc.Checklist(
                    id="slot-filter",
                    options=[
                        {"label": Slot, "value": Slot}
                        for Slot in np.sort(dataframe.Slot.unique())
                    ],
                    value=[],                            
                    # multi=True,
                    # clearable=True,
                    # searchable=True,
                    labelStyle = {'display': 'block'},
                    className="filter01",
                ),
```

WHat I get:

[image]

What I expect:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847745/how-to-divide-a-python-dash-checklist-into-several-columns

Comment: I hope that I can do it like that, but my thing can't be seperated. I want to display it with two lines from one column which is Slot.

Comment: I solve this problem with display: block and column-count: 2; on css

Comment: Good to hear. Pls do consider answering your own question below, so that it could help someone else who has the same problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

On py, set

```
labelStyle = {'display': 'block'},
```

and on css,

```
.filter01 {
    column-count: 2;
}
```